# Within a column, creating a range between two elements in a list in PySpark

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark, range, element

I have a column called ID. In that column, each row is a list of strings of numbers... yea that's a mouthful.

**INCOMING DATA**

> ID:
>
> ['100','105']
>
> ['200']
>
> ['205','210']

I am looking for something where any rows with more than one element would be parsed out between the first and last number. E.g.

**DESIRED OUTPUT**

> ID:
>
> [100,101,102,103,104,105]
>
> [200]
>
> [205,206,207,208,209,210]

Here is my attempt, I don't know how to structure the syntax or even if the logic will even work:

```
temp_list = []

df = df.withColumn("ID",
when(df['ID'].count() > 0, 

first_number = int(df['ID'][0])
last_number = int(df['ID'][1])

x = range(first_number, last_number)

for n in x:
    temp_list.append(n)
return temp_list)

.otherwise(int(df['ID']))
```

So I'm saying to create an empty list. Working with the ID column, if any row has more than one element, define the first number and the last number.

Using the range function, iterate between those two numbers and append that into the empty list and return it.

Otherwise, keep the value the same, but make it an int. There's a lot wrong with it but any pointers in the right direction will be very appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the spark 2.4+, there is a function `sequence`.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *

data = [
    ['100','105'],
    ['200'],
    ['205','210']
]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ArrayType(StringType()))

df2 = df.withColumn('sequence', when(size('value') > 1, sequence(col('value')[0].cast('int'), col('value')[1].cast('int'))).otherwise(col('value')))
df2.show(truncate=False)

+----------+------------------------------+
|value     |sequence                      |
+----------+------------------------------+
|[100, 105]|[100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105]|
|[200]     |[200]                         |
|[205, 210]|[205, 206, 207, 208, 209, 210]|
+----------+------------------------------+
```